# What is the term to refer to the working tree when running git diff?

Tags: git-diff

Running `git diff <branch>` will diff the working tree against the `<branch>` however I'm using an indirect text editor command that takes two arguments.

`git diff HEAD <branch>` almost does what I want, however it doesn't include working tree changes.

How to specify the current working tree when running git diff?

Comment: Can one argument be blank?

Comment: The question assumes it can't be. Assuming this - is there a way to refer to the working tree? If not - the answer is simply - "it's not possible"